# How to check type of object in Python?

Tags: python

I have some value in variable `v`, how do I check its type?

Hint: It is NOT `v.dtype`.

When I do `type(v)` in the debugger, I get

```
type(v) = {type} <type 'h5py.h5r.Reference'>
```

or

```
type(v) = {type} <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
```

How to check these values at runtime?

"Check" means calculate the boolean result, saying if the type is given.

**UPDATE**

In the so-called "duplicate" question it is said that to compare the type one should use

```
type(v) is str
```

which implicitly assumes that types are strings. Are they?

Comment: What do you mean by "*check*"? Do you want to print the type name? Do you want to compare the type to some known type?

Comment: I want to compare to this type next time.

Comment: Re: "UPDATE". No, types are not strings, nor does the duplicate answer imply that they are.

Comment: What "str" may mean then? Straightrunning? Stride? May be Stradivarius?

Answer (score 33):

## What type() means:

I think your question is a bit more general than I originally thought. `type()` with one argument returns the `type` or `class` of the object. So if you have `a = 'abc'` and use `type(a)` this returns `str` because the variable `a` is a string. If `b = 10`, `type(b)` returns `int`.

See also [python documentation on type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type).

---

## For comparisons:

If you want a comparison you could use: `if type(v) == h5py.h5r.Reference` (to check if it is a `h5py.h5r.Reference` instance).

But it is recommended that one uses `if isinstance(v, h5py.h5r.Reference)` but then *also* subclasses will evaluate to `True`.

If you want to print the class use `print v.__class__.__name__`.

More generally: You can compare if two instances have the same class by using `type(v) is type(other_v)` or `isinstance(v, other_v.__class__)`.

Comment: Is this true for "class" types also?

Comment: Also in "duplicate" answer it is said to compare with `type(o) is str`. Does this means that types are strings?

Comment: The ``type(o)`` returns just the class (type) of ``o``. I think it's roughly equivalent to calling ``o.__class__``.

Comment: I don't know what the use-case is but I think one should either use ``isinstance(o, class_to_compare_o_with)`` or ``duck typing``.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: With `type(o) is str` you check whether the object `o` is of the type `str`. If you want to check if it's an integer you would use `type(o) is int`.

Answer (score 28):

Use any of the following:

```py
isinstance(v, type_name)
```

```py
type(v) is type_name
```

```py
type(v) == type_name
```

where **type_name** can be one of:

- `None`
- `bool`
- `int`
- `float`
- `complex`
- `str`
- `list`
- `tuple`
- `set`
- `dict`

and, of course,

- custom types (classes)

Comment: Type comparisons should be done with ``isinstance``. See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type